# Why can't I change the theme of my Google-Chrome Dev-tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, themes, google-chrome-devtools

I am running Windows 7, and following [this tutorial](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/chrome-devtools-theme/) to change the theme of the Google Chrome Dev-Tools.

I did download [this theme](https://gist.github.com/tholex/5214137), extracted it and then copied and pasted the code from its `Custom.css` file to the file in the same name in my `Custom.css` located at

C:\Users\Zarah\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets

**But it seems to have no effect. The tutorial states that a restart is not required, but i did try restarting Chrome and it did not help either.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Support for Custom.css has been removed from Chrome in version 32.
See more:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207474/custom-css-has-stopped-working-in-32-0-1700-76-m-google-chrome-update